# Refine Search Results

Tags: search

I'm looking for a simple way to achieve search filtering like this : http://ckclinical.co.uk/search/

They are obviously pointing people to a empty search and then filtering by category.  I've spent hours running round in circles :)
Thanks.

Comment: @user2924 - I must be missing something but I'm unclear still what you mean by *"like this"?*  Can you also please specify your basic requirements?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I think he is asking for the "Refine your search" box in that website, If I am not wrong then.

Comment: @ntechi - In part I ask people to clarify so I can hopefully train new users to put more time and effort into their questions. It helps everyone if they can provide a clear and consist description. This site is designed to be a search engine destination for great answers to common questions and if questions have titles that mean nothing and questions that are very vague, it's no good for anybody.

Comment: @ntechi @MikeSchinkel - apologies for any vagueness, I thought it was better to provide a link and reference the filtering rather than produce a longer question.  Will know better next time ;)

Comment: Look at this answer to [Is there any multiple filter/criteria plugin for wordpress ?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8224/is-there-any-multiple-filter-criteria-plugin-for-wordpress/8237#8237) you can code the ba_search_with_filters function to output select dropdown with just the categories you want.

Answer (score 3):

Search is a big topic and therefore I can only guess the direction you want to go to. Like @MikeSchinkel in his comment was asking for more, I can for the moment only provide a list of links of which one might come close to what you need:

- [Refine search by category (How-To)](http://code.hyperspatial.com/all-code/wordpress-code/refine-search-by-category/);
- [Building a Custom “Search By Category” WordPress Plugin: New Premium Tutorial (Tutorial)](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/building-a-custom-search-by-category-wordpress-plugin-new-plus-tutorial/) ;
- [Faceted Search (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faceted-search/);
- [Search Unleashed (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-unleashed/);
- [Search API (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search/);
- [WordPress Sphinx Search Plugin (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.ivinco.com/software/wordpress-sphinx-search-plugin/);
- [Make WordPress’ search function suck Less (How-To)](http://yoast.com/wordpress-search/);

Comment: Thanks @hakre - Faceted Search looked promising if I can restrict a few categories.  Otherwise the second link sounds exactly what I am looking for....however tutsplus is down at the moment.  Will report back.

Comment: @usewr2924 - good to read!